# is there any way to save current content with jquery as mhtml

Tags: jquery, mhtml

Is there any way when client click to "Save page for later" to convert current content with jquery to mhtml string and send it to my server, to make a preview file for client.

Regards

Comment: you mean create a mhtml file ???

Comment: yes with current webpage content (for example some tutorial)